# Want to output post title with meta-tags at same time on MySQL of WordPress

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I want to edit meta-tags of a blog page of my WordPress blog using SQL editting tool such as MySQL workbench.

I want SQL output such as below. Can not?

```
# post_title, metatag
'metadev', 'hoge'
'metadev', 'fuga'
```

SELECT * FROM yuis_yuisorgblog.wp_posts;

Output of above SQL is below.

```
# ID, post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_password, post_name, to_ping, pinged, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, post_content_filtered, post_parent, guid, menu_order, post_type, post_mime_type, comment_count
'164', '1', '2018-08-20 15:49:53', '2018-08-20 06:49:53', '<p>metatagdev</p>\n', 'metatagdev', '', 'publish', 'closed', 'open', '', 'metatagdev', '', '', '2018-08-20 15:49:53', '2018-08-20 06:49:53', 'metatagdev', '0', 'http://yuis.org/blog/?p=164', '0', 'post', '', '0'
```

SELECT * FROM yuis_yuisorgblog.wp_term_relationships;

Output of above SQL is below.

```
# object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order
'164', '5', '0'
'164', '6', '0'
```

SELECT * FROM yuis_yuisorgblog.wp_term_taxonomy;

Output of above SQL is below.

```
# term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count
'5', '5', 'post_tag', '', '0', '1'
'6', '6', 'post_tag', '', '0', '1'
```

SELECT * FROM yuis_yuisorgblog.wp_terms;

Output of above SQL is below.

```
# term_id, name, slug, term_group
'5', 'hoge', 'hoge', '0'
'6', 'fuga', 'fuga', '0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT post_title,name FROM wp_posts 
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE post_type = 'post'
```